# jquery ajax call from user input number to update available quantity

Tags: jquery, ajax, input

using jquery, I want to get user input value and the product value and pass it to backend . once user changes input value , do an ajax call, to hit a java backend. we need to pass a product number and quantity value , that will help generate the available quantity based from the quantity and product number. can anyone help me how I can do this task?

```
<table id="myTable">
        <tr>
        <th>Product Line</th>
        <th >Quantity</th>
        <th>Available Quantity</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id="product-number">test product <br> 56789</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="product-quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="999"></td>
        <td id="available-quantity"></td>
        </tr>
        
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should listen on the change of input value then run an ajax call. Then on success, render the response of your backend

```
<table id="myTable">
        <tr>
        <th>Product Line</th>
        <th >Quantity</th>
        <th>Available Quantity</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="product-number">test product <br> 56789</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="product-quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="999"></td>
            <td id="available-quantity"></td>
        </tr>  
</table>
```

```
$(function(){
    $('#product-quantity').on('keyup', function() {
       // if input value is changed, run the ajax call here
       $.ajax({
          .... <- fill in all required details here such as url, method, etc.
          success: function (data) {
            // then on ajax success, display the results from your backend
            $('#available-quantity').html(data)
          }
       })
    })
})
```

Reference on how to call ajax via jquery:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/